# Change the color of text in validate() in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I wonder if it is possible to change the color of text in `validate()` in a shiny app since there is not an id like for example when you use `textOutput()`.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput('in1', 'Check some letters', choices = head(LETTERS)),
  selectizeInput('in2', 'Select a state', choices = state.name),
  plotOutput('plot')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    validate(
      need(input$in1, 'Check at least one letter!'),
      need(input$in2 != '', 'Please choose a state.')
    )
    plot(1:10, main = paste(c(input$in1, input$in2), collapse = ', '))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide a CSS style as described here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(

    tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML("
      .shiny-output-error-validation {
        color: #ff0000;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    "))
    ),

    checkboxGroupInput('in1', 'Check some letters', choices = head(LETTERS)),
    selectizeInput('in2', 'Select a state', choices = state.name),
    plotOutput('plot')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        validate(
            need(input$in1, 'Check at least one letter!'),
            need(input$in2 != '', 'Please choose a state.')
            )
        plot(1:10, main = paste(c(input$in1, input$in2), collapse = ', '))
        })
    }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Result

[image]

Comment: markus I wonder why the message "Please choose a state" is not affected

Comment: @firmo23 It is actually. To see it, change the `choices` in `selectizeInput` to `choices = c("", state.name))`
`